# Office 365 GRAPH API using visual studio workflow [Error]

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I am trying to read mailbox using GRAPH API using visual studio workflow. I am getting bad request.
here is the error

**RequestorId: 807227cd-f8b8-76ee-0000-000000000000. Details: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. Exception details: System.ArgumentException: JsonWebToken.Issuer != clientId@realm at Microsoft.Activities.Messaging.SendHttpRequest.OnReceiveResponse(NativeActivityContext context, Bookmark bookmark, Object value) at System.Activities.Runtime.BookmarkWorkItem.Execute(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) Exception from activity SendHttpRequest HttpGet Switch Sequence Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.Activities.CallHTTPWebService Stage 1 Sequence Flowchart Sequence GraphApiCall.WorkflowXaml_f7553f05_3008_4870_afd7_1f84206e69a2**

Please see below screenshots

```
https://login.microsoft.com/cubiclogics.com/oauth2/token
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[call graph api using Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAtKt.png)

[workflow error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTrcZ.png)

Thanks for help

Comment: I tested graph api in postman its working fine.

Comment: With only this information it will be hard to help you. It could just too many things. Can you please share the Error Message you are receiving?

Comment: Hi Karlheinz, thanks for reply, I updated postman screenshot above post, please see that, same HTTP call i am trying to implement using visual studio workflow, I am getting bad request.

Comment: Actually this VS workflow we implemented inside sharepoint hosted app, and trying to read mailbox, but its failing first level to get access token, Using JavaScript i can able to read mailbox, but we need this using VS workflow.

Comment: I am not familiar with postman and VS workflow.
As from the urls I'm guessing that you want to authenticate on behalf of a user and now want to get a token.
Could it be that you are reusing the code (for all requests) that you got in the [first step](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user#2-get-authorization)?

Comment: Is there no possibility to get a detailed error message. Maybe there are logfiles that contain the full error response?

Comment: thanks Karlheinz for your support, please do me a favoure, vote my question.

Comment: we are tracking all logs in sharepoint list itself, I already posted logs screenshots.

Comment: Did you set the `code`-property in your request? Keep in mind this authorization_code is not infinitely valid and has to be fetched again each time you log in.
"Bad Request" is just the status. Sadly without the full detailed Error Response I cannot help you further (Graph always returns what went wrong). I can only refer you to the tutorial in the (documentation)[https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user#3-get-a-token]
You should also include a tag regarding sharepoint maybe `sharepoint` or `sharepoint-online`, maybe there are people familiar with your problem

Comment: I really appreciate your effort, please vote my question

Comment: @PrashantPrakash please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your post so that folks can help you.

Comment: Sorry Michael, next time i will keep my post in better way.

Comment: As @PrashantPrakash 's comment, you should provide the detail information about your response. Such as the Error message

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm stating the obvious here but the Code Request URI in your screenshot (Visual Studio) is directed at https://**login.microsoft.com**/cubiclogics.com/oauth2/tokens and your working Postman-Screenshot displays https://login**.microsoftonline**.com/cubiclogics.com/oauth2/tokens

Typo? :)

Comment: I tried both https://login.microsoft.com/.. and  https://login.microsoftonline.com/.. in visual studio workflow got same error, but in postman both url are working fine.